# What does the VBA TRIM function return if the value is EMPTY vs NULL?

Tags: excel, vba

So I understand that a worksheet cell that is EMPTY is devoid of any content.
But a worksheet cell that is NULL is what?

Moreover, I'm using the VBA TRIM function and the cell is EMPTY or NULL, what does the TRIM function return?

Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: have you tried printing what both return?

Comment: afaik, IsEmpty and comparing to vbnullstring report the same from a truly blank cell. Cells containing a zero-length string (e.g. `""`) are not truly blank.

Comment: Also, AFAIK, a cell is never Null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned a cell is never Null, a Variant can hold the specialvalue NULL
As an answer on your question Trim on a Empty Cell will give a zero-length string

Comment: So if I trim an empty cell, get a zero-length string, and then write that zero-length string back to the cell, this means the cell is no longer empty correct? If it contains a zero-length string, what is it considered then if it's no longer an empty cell?

Answer (score 2):

Excel does not have a NULL datatype so a cell cannot contain NULL:

however a cell can contain an error and that error can be #NULL!

Its very rare to meet that error type - its mainly there to signify that an explicit intersection of 2 ranges does not actually intersect.